# I only want to show the blogs posted by the current logged in user in liferay portlet

Tags: liferay

**I need some help with LIFERAY Blog Portlet.**
On a page I have added the blog portlet & the blogs posted by different users are shown there, but on a different page that is shown to the user only after logging in, there I want that the blog portlet should show only the blogs posted by the logged in user.
how can I do that?

Comment: You have to alter default blog logic by writing an hook plugin. It's quite easy.

Comment: ok, but I don't know which file I have to modify. Is it a jsp or a service?

Comment: Let me find the file today..